# JQuery - Using Dialog Few Simple Questions

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have been trying use dialog boxes to take user input to set elements on the page.

A few things are not working like usual, can you explain?

- If set a GLOBAL var "NumberVariable" and try to increment the variable from a button click from inside the "Dialog window" the variable will not be incremented?

Also after creating a new element and appending it to a div, the trying to "Hide" the element using a class it does not work? Can some one explain?

I have heavily commented the code so you can understand what I mean a little better, if you just try and create a new Page/Link and click "Apply" the "Link" and "containment-wrapper" is created but the function will not hide all the others with the same class ".containment-wrapper".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at a javascript console to see if there are any errors? I noticed you declared the variable without a var --  e.g. i would declare a javascript variable as:

```
var NumberVariable = 0;
```

Also, try adding this inside the apply link function

```
        var InterHeight = $("#Interface_Height").val();
        var InterWidth = $("#Interface_Width").val();

        //SET CONTAINMENT WRAPPER INTERFACE HEIGHT/WIDTH USING GLOBAL VARS SET IN (INTERFACE SETTINGS)
        $("#Wrapper-" + WrapNum).css({"height": InterHeight, "width": InterWidth});
```

Comment: I have tried that and it still does not work? No I have not used a javascript console...

Comment: I think the problem was because I did not declare the variables for the height/width I will use the console more!! Thanks anyways!

Comment: I like your theme, by the way.  If you right click in chrome or firefox and click 'Inspect Element' you will find a javascript console.  I am seeing the error "uncaught ReferenceError: InterHeight is not defined" when I click on apply link